# Criteria of SUMIF Function referring to data previously in table

Tags: excel, formula, sumifs

Is there a way to add values in Excel based off of values previously in table?

For example, in the table I currently have, is there a way to exclude adding the 1 from the "Attended" column in the "Sonics and Cold Cash" row because I already had a row with "Sonics" and "1" in attended? I don't want to add a 1 to the SUMIF function if I have already attended that team once before.

I hope this is clear enough for some help. Thank you!

[image]

edit: So far, I have a table that tracks how many times a team has been "attended". This works, however I am trying to use linear optimization for scheduling, and using the results table has some linearity problems. I'm trying to find a way to only use the table instead of a second, results table.

Comment: @TerryW I have edited my original post. I'm looking to keep everything contained to one formula instead of using a results table.

Comment: what do you mean by `linear optimization`? what does your result table look like at the moment, and  what do you want to do with the *ideal* result table? are you able to show what the *ideal* result table should look like?

Comment: at the last row (Day 4).. the " Attended " value should be 1 too right? (since Storm already appeared in line 1)